# how to listen to --safe-area-inset-bottom env changes

Tags: css, reactjs, getcomputedstyle

I want to write a hook which returns the latest `--safe-area-inset-bottom` value.

```
const safeAreaInsetBottom = useSafeAreaInsetBottom();
```

the first value is easy to get. Something like the following will do:

```
getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--safe-area-inset-bottom')
```

but this would not consider future changes of the viewport (i.e. a mobile screen changing from portrait to landscape). I was wondering what would be the best way to achieve this (listeners, mutation observers etc..)